# ASP.NET Core with Duallistbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bootstrap-duallistbox

In my ASP.NET Core (.NET5) project, I use Bootstrap Duallistbox (bootstrap4-duallistbox@4.0.2). In the Razor page, I have a model that include `Departments` field as a `List<Department>` and in the page, I wrote the following code

```
<select id="Departments" asp-for="Departments" class="duallistbox" 
        multiple="multiple" 
        asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentID">
</select>

<script>
    $('.duallistbox').bootstrapDualListbox();
</script>
```

The `ViewBag` is coming from this function

```
private void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(object selectedDepartment = null)
{
    var departmentsQuery = _department.ListAllQuerableAsync();
    ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(departmentsQuery, "ID", "Name", 
                                          selectedDepartment);
}
```

If I inspect this `ViewBag`, I can see there is some values in the `SelectedValues`.

[image]

The result is this 2 listboxes but no items are selected.

[image]

Also, if I select some items and press the submit button, the variable `Departments` doesn't have any selected values.

Do you have any ideas how I can fix this issues?

### Update

I have changed the function `PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList`.

```
private void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(List<long> selectedDepartment = null)
{
    var departmentsQuery = _department.ListAllQuerableAsync().ToList();
    ViewBag.DepartmentID = new MultiSelectList(departmentsQuery, "ID", "Name", 
                                               selectedDepartment);
}
```

So, now I can see the selected items.

[image]

When I press the submit button, the selected values are not in the model. For this reason, I added another listbox

```
<select id="Departments" asp-for="Departments"></select>
<script>
    $('.duallistbox').bootstrapDualListbox();
    $('#editButton').click(function () {
        $("[id*=bootstrap-duallistbox-selected-list_] option").each(function () {
            $('#Departments').append(
               new Option($(this).text(), $(this).val(), true, true)
            );
        });
        $("form").submit();
    })
</script>
```

So, now when the submit is clicked, I add all the selected items in the new listbox but those values are not present in the model.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The result is this 2 listboxes but no items are selected.

You should use **selectedDepartment.ID** to pass the selected item

> Also, if I select some items and press the submit button, the variable Departments doesn't have any selected values.

Do you want to pass the selected items to controller action? You can use **jquery to get the selected value and then pass** it.

You can check my demo:

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var selectedDepartment = new Department() { ID = 2, Name = "name2" };
        var departmentsQuery = new List<Department>()
        {
            new Department{ ID=1,Name="name1"},
            new Department{ ID=2,Name="name2"},
            new Department{ ID=3,Name="name3"},
        };
        ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(departmentsQuery, "ID", "Name",selectedDepartment.ID);
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GETIT(List<Department> department)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model Department
<select id="Departments" class="duallistbox" multiple="multiple"
    asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentID">
</select>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="PassValue" />
</div>

@section Scripts
{
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- plugin -->
<script src="https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/bootstrap-duallistbox/v3.0.2/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/bootstrap-duallistbox/v3.0.2/bootstrap-duallistbox.css">
<script>
    $('.duallistbox').bootstrapDualListbox();
    $("#PassValue").click(function () {
        var Dep = [];
        $("[id*=bootstrap-duallistbox-selected-list_] option").each(function () {
            var data = {
                ID: $(this).val(),
                Name: $(this).text()
            };
            Dep.push(data);
        });

        var model = {
            department: Dep
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Home/GETIT',
            data: model,
            success: function () {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! After a long search, your answer is the best